# I have 5 regular receptacles outside with one GFCIS on same circuit is this legal?

Tags: electrical

I have a new house come to find out there are regular receptacles on same line as GFCI. Is this legal

Comment: It could well be that the one GFCI receptacle is providing GFCI protection to the other five "standard" receptacles.

If you press the test button on the GFCI receptacle it will disconnect power to that receptacle, and does it also interrupt power to the other five? If the others are connected through the "load terminals" of the GFCI receptacle, it will do so. If it is connected this way, then a ground fault on any of the standard receptacles will trip the GFCI receptacle and interrupt power to all six receptacles.

Comment: It is perfectly OK to have GFCI receptacles and standard ones on the same circuit, if they are wired correctly.

Comment: You can get a tester which will test GFCI function: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mibiIDm4kQw . Plug it into any of the outside receptacles and test for GFCI protection.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a sticker at each of the outside outlets saying `GFCI Protected`?

If not, this is a code violation.  Raise an objection to the builder / seller / warranty company.  They need to put the stickers on if they are protected, or fit a GFCI device somewhere if they are not.

Hopefully the GFCI device will be sited indoors - it will last a lot longer there.